# Using the Insert Into command correctly in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I just started to learn some SQL syntaxes and now i stuck already when I try to insert data from a Query into a specific database.

I have 5 DB's
db1,db2,db3,db4,db5
in every db there are the same tables lets say dbo.fruits

when I now select db2 and open a query I can easly enter new fruits into my db2 by using :

```
Insert into dbo.Fruits (Name, Description)
 values ('banana', 'yummy');
```

But if I don't select db2 before. How do I enter my bananas into dbo.fruits from db2 ?

I thought

```
Insert into [db2] dbo.Fruits (Name, Description)
 values ('banana', 'yummy');
```

but it's not working :/, of course I googled, but didnt find the right answer.

Comment: Maybe you can collapse the databases into one in the first place. Less redundancy.

Comment: i wish i could haha. Na all my colleagues are professionals and i have to catch up now ;) i have to take the dbs we have here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Insert into [db2].dbo.Fruits (Name, Description)
values ('banana', 'yummy');
```

or if your user is dbowner you can do

```
Insert into [db2].Fruits (Name, Description)
values ('banana', 'yummy');
```

Comment: Danke Jürgen :) i will accept the answer in 13minutes, you are too fast :P

Answer (score 0):

The easiest will be to remember to put the database name first for every SQL statement/query. 
Something like: `SELECT * FROM [db1].[dbo].[Fruits]`

ie. `...[DatabaseName].[SchemaName].[TableName]`